# XSLT for copying content from same-name elements into sibling nodes

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an XML file where I need to copy the value of each < Source > node and insert it into corresponding < Target > node (overwrite, where not empty) .

XML file has this structure:

```
<Message>
    <Id>VARIABLE_1</Id>
    <Code>VAR</Code>
    <Source>TEXT 1</Source>
    <Source>TEXT 2</Source>
    <Source/>
    <Source>TEXT 3</Source>
    <Comment/>
    <Target>SOMETHING 1</Target>
    <Target>SOMETHING 2</Target>
    <Target/>
    <Target>SOMETHING 3</Target>
    <Comment/>
</Message>
```

I need to "transform" it into this:

```
<Message>
    <Id>VARIABLE_1</Id>
    <Code>VAR</Code>
    <Source>TEXT 1</Source>
    <Source>TEXT 2</Source>
    <Source/>
    <Source>TEXT 3</Source>
    <Comment/>
    <Target>TEXT 1</Target>
    <Target>TEXT 2</Target>
    <Target/>
    <Target>TEXT 3</Target>
    <Comment/>
</Message>
```

So, essentially, every < Target > node will inherit the value of corresponding preceding < Source > node.

There is always going to be a matching number of < Source > and < Target > nodes, but some parent  nodes might contain only one < Source > and < Target > node and some might contain anywhere up to 5 of each (in this example case there are 3 of each).

I've tried this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//Target">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="//Target/preceding-sibling::Source"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it copies only the very first < Source > node and inserts it into every subsequent < Target > node. And I need them to be copied in sequence - first  node gets copied into first < Target > node, second < Source > node gets copied into second < Target > node, etc.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Target">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="count(preceding-sibling::Target) + 1" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="../Source[$i]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:template match="Target">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="../Source[count(current()/preceding-sibling::Target) + 1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. Is there any way to restrict processing of nodes only to those parent < Message > elements that have <Code  >VAR</ Code > child elements?

Comment: You could limit the processing to `Target ` elements that have a sibling `Code` element whose value is `"VAR"` by using `<xsl:template match="Target[../Code='VAR']">`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Solution -->
    <xsl:template match="Target">        
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="../Source[substring-after(current(),' ') = substring-after(.,' ')]"/>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is as expected.